# Yii2 How can I create a Menu item pointing to a detail view

Tags: view, menu, yii2, menuitem, detailview

I use the typical frontend menu from Yii2. Usually the menu items according to the main.php are like

```
$menuItems[] = [
        ['label' => 'Home', 'url' => ['/site/index']],
        ['label' => 'About', 'url' => ['/site/about']],
        ['label' => 'Contact', 'url' => ['/site/contact']],
    ];
```

In case of pointing to a detail view, this is not working. I cannot use

```
$menuItems[] = [
            ['label' => 'Member', 'url' => ['/member/view' . '&id=' . $id]],
```

also this is not working

```
$menuItems = [
['label' => 'Member', 'url' => Url::to('member/view', ['id' => $id])],
```

How can I point from menu items to detail views?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be

```
$menuItems[] = ['label' => 'Member', 'url' => ['/member/view', 'id' => $id]],
```